# Google Package with ESP8266 to Gen Tokens for HTTP Requests in MicroPython (Package Unavailable)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pip, iot, esp8266

Title: Using Google Package with ESP8266 to Generate Tokens for HTTP Requests in MicroPython (Package Unavailable)

Body:

I am working on a project involving an ESP8266 microcontroller and Firebase. The microcontroller runs MicroPython, and unfortunately, it does not have built-in support for connecting embedded devices to Firebase. To establish a connection, Firebase requires a token generated from a JSON file.

My challenge is that due to the limited memory size and Package Unavailable for the ESP8266, I'm encountering issues when using the HTTP protocol to send requests to Firebase, as the headers become too long and GOOGLE Package Unavailable.

I have been exploring the possibility of using the Google package (installed via pip install google) to facilitate token generation, but I've learned that this package is not available for MicroPython.

Given this limitation, I am seeking guidance on alternative approaches or libraries that can help me achieve the same goal, considering the memory constraints of the ESP8266 and the need to keep HTTP headers within manageable limits.

Please share any code examples, resources, or suggestions that could help me address this issue, considering the unavailability of the "google" package for MicroPython. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

#### What I've Tried:

- I attempted to install the "google" package using pip install google on MicroPython, but it is not compatible.
- I investigated methods for reducing the size of HTTP headers or alternative methods of token generation but have not found a satisfactory solution.

##### What I Was Expecting:

- I expected that installing the "google" package would provide a straightforward way to generate tokens for Firebase.
- I was hoping to find a solution that would allow me to work within the memory limitations of the ESP8266 while connecting to Firebase using the token.